# rewriteurl - redirect to new path

Tags: php, .htaccess

i want redirect to new/index.php when people type

```
site.com
site.com/index.php
site.com/index.html
site.com/index.htm
```

So this code below maybe right ?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^index\.(html|php|htm)$ new/index.php
```

Comment: Why would people be typing `site.com/index.html`?

Comment: more importantly, do you not know if it is right because you didn't try it? Add [L] to the end of that line.

Comment: because i try site.com/index.html and get an 404 page ~.~

Comment: @arxanas : many visitors type like this :-s i can not ask them do not type like it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this instead :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^(index\.(html?|php))?$ /new/index.php [L,NC,QSA,R=301]
```

If you don't want people to see there address bar changed to /new, remove the `R=301` flag.

You can have more information about [mod_rewrite here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html)

Answer (score 1):

Almost, you're not making the match against `site.com`, so on top of what you have, add:

```
RewriteRule ^$ new/index.php [L]
```